# UDP Client Binding on .NET7 for MacOS

Tags: c#, .net, macos

I have a method to create a bunch of UDP sockets for sending out broadcast messages to specific devices.  This code works 100% on Windows, but I've been tasked with creating a MacOS version.  For whatever reason, I throw an SocketException on binding the UdpClient Socket to a specific IPEndPoint and port ("Address already in use").  I'm sure there's something silly than I'm just ignorant of but all my research has come up with nothing.  Any assistance would be helpful.

MacOS 13.4.1, .NET 7.0.306

```
private static List<IPAddress> GetEndpoints()
    {
        List<IPAddress> AddressList = new List<IPAddress>();
        NetworkInterface[] Interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

        foreach (NetworkInterface I in Interfaces)
        {
            if ((I.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback) && I.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                foreach (var Unicast in I.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
                {
                    if (Unicast?.Address?.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        AddressList.Add(Unicast.Address);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return AddressList;
    }

    private static void CreateSockets()
    {
        List<IPAddress> Endpoints = GetEndpoints();
        foreach (IPAddress A in Endpoints)
        {
            try
            {
                UdpClient Udp = new UdpClient();
                Udp.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 100000;
                Udp.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
                Udp.EnableBroadcast = true;
                Udp.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
                Udp.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(A, 44444));  // This line throws the exception.
                ReceiveDataAsync(Udp, ReceiveDataCallback);
                UdpClients.Add(Udp);
                if (UdpClientBuffer.ContainsKey(Udp))
                {
                    UdpClientBuffer[Udp] = String.Empty;
                }
                else
                {
                    UdpClientBuffer.Add(Udp, String.Empty);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string S = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `UdpClient` in a fire-and-forget manner like that... that's probably the cause of the problem: you don't seem to be ensuring that the `IPAddress A` is unique, so your code will create two `UdpClient` instances with the same binding - I don't think this is a Mac vs. Windows issue, but a "works-on-my-machine" issue - whereas it would fail for the same reason on a Windows box that had the same (multihomed?) config as your Mac box. (Also, please _don't_ use Uppercase single letters for variable names: use non-cryptic `camelCase` names for readability).

Comment: @Dai I'm not using it in a fire-and-forget manner.  There is other code that is utilizing the UdpClient after the fact.  I just haven't shown it because it never gets that far.  I did ensure via the locals window that all the IPAddress are unique.  However I did discover the issue and will post it.

Comment: What if Mac-host already contains app with Udp-socket bound to 44444 port and one of the host's interfaces?

Comment: @Chris _"I'm not using it in a fire-and-forget manner."_ - where do you call `.Dispose()` on the `UdpClient` instances? Your code also will leak `UdpClient` instances if an exception is thrown inside your `try/catch` block, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2000

Comment: @Dai I have other code that calls `.Dispose()` on those instances after a pre-determined period of inactivity, but wasn't relevant to the issue I was experiencing, so in the interest of providing a minimal example, it wasn't included.  I appreciate your concern.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the reason why the address was in use, even though I thought it wasn't.  I have Parallels running on my machine to support windows and had created a port forwarding rule within Parallels, which bound to every interface on that port.  Removing the port forwarding rule resulted in expected operation.

Comment: As a general rule, when the runtime says the port is in use, the port is in use

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and it sure was.  I just didn't think that there was any other application that would be using that port.  I forgot about my specific configuration.  I knew it was something silly. ;)